# Efficiently encode String to Stream

Tags: c#, memory-management, encoding, stream, allocation

I am currently using the following snippet to write an UTF8 encoded string to a network stream in a performance critical section:

```
private static readonly ArrayPool<byte> POOL = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared;

private static readonly Encoding ENCODING = Encoding.UTF8;

private async ValueTask Write(string text)
{
    var length = ENCODING.GetByteCount(text);

    var buffer = POOL.Rent(length);

    try 
    { 
        ENCODING.GetBytes(text, 0, length, buffer, 0);

        await OutputStream.WriteAsync(buffer.AsMemory(0, length)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    finally
    {
        POOL.Return(buffer);
    }
}
```

My feeling is that this can be written more efficiently and maybe even allocation free using one of the `Span<T>` and `Memory<T>` based overloads, but I fail to see how.

My understanding would be that I can somehow convert the `Span<char>` representation of the string on the fly into something that I can pass to the stream (e.g. `ReadOnlyMemory<byte>` without the need to use an intermediate buffer (neither allocated nor rented) - so just by accessing the underlying bytes of the string (there is already memory allocated for them - why would I need to allocate new?).

Comment: If you look up `GetByteCount` you'll see its documentation already points you towards other tools, such as `GetMaxByteCount` or `Encoder.Convert`.

Comment: Are you not already allocation-free by using the memory pool? I might note that Async methods may not always be faster than sync methods.

Comment: @JonasH: Thanks, I updated the last paragraph to make my understanding more clear. After another hour of research I get the feeling that this cannot be done with `async` because the string can get out of scope.

Comment: You may be able to access the underlying bytes in the string but bear in mind that the encoding of strings in .NET is UTF-16, not UTF-8, so if that's the required encoding, doesn't look like you can evade *some* kind of buffer.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever, sounds legit. After investigating Kestrel's source code I could probably expose the inner buffer of the stream via the `IBufferWriter` interface to directly to write to that buffer instead. See [this method](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/702b937577122445498a2d800c7ca1782a1b3556/src/Shared/ServerInfrastructure/BufferExtensions.cs#L120). This would save me the allocation / buffer at least at this place.

Comment: Did you end up finding an efficient way to do that?
I was looking for the exact same thing an ran into your question. This seems like a method .NET should include these days, something like:
CopyStringToStream(Encoding Encoding, ReadOnlySpan<char> Chars, Stream ResultStream, int BufferSize = 0)